# GPS Location Is Null on Device but Works on Emulator

Tags: android

i am testing the following code on my device, which is giving me `location` object `null`. gps is activated on my device but even then it is not giving me the location.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (l==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location is null", 300).show();
        }
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geocoding"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.geocoding.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Help Would be appriciated :-)

Comment: It can return null so you should poll it in a thread etc.

Comment: The GPS might be connected, but if you're inside a building the location will not be updated. You're taking the location from the last known one and not using the it realtime. This might be problematic, because if you change your location on a cloudy day, it will remain the last known one. You can include a check from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` if this one is null and if it suits your needs of course :)

Comment: if i try `Criteria c = new Criteria();
  l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.getBestProvider(c, false));` this would it be better ?

Comment: is it working on the emulator..if it is working  and not working in device that means your device is not getting the gps fixes .or else u can try with what @Usman suggested.

Comment: Maybe it is not null, after your phone has received a GPS fix before. Try turning on your phone with Google Maps (with GPS also turned on) and wait until you have a GPS fix (do not do this indoors, because it is hard to get GPS fixes inside buildings). After that you will probably have something different to null here. By the way: according to the documentation it will also return null if GPS is not turned on on the device...

Comment: `lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
  l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` i  just tried getting the location like this. but it is still null. . why ?

Comment: @ Try with using location listener Class check weather you are getting he gps fixes or not.just try to move your device.when ur testing

Comment: @Abhijit that's obvious . i will get the location cuz lastKnownLocation will give me location object != null. problem is i want to get location when application starts . .

Comment: @Usman OK SO WHEN YOU ARE TESTING IN EMULATOR WHAT VALUES IT GIVING IS IT GIVING THE DDMS LAST LATITUDE LONGITUDE VALUES..

Comment: @Abhijit The same values that i give it from DDMS the same values i retrived from lastKnownLocation method.

Comment: @Usman Its the problem in your device its simply not getting the fixes from satellite so try to test it in a open space.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes, that on creation location is already known. Most time, it will be wrong. Proper code should register LocationListener to LocationManager, and wait some time to get reply. Time can be different each time, depends on what kind of location are you waiting for. It might help to move location getting to onResume() instead, maybe that time, it has higher chance to be available already. But use asynchronous calls and wait for you reply, if your application should be worth usage.

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html